# React - Exporting Context Provider gives me error: "Element type is invalid: expected a string [...] but got: undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Summary**

I have a file where I create a component with a React Context Provider, which I exported to another file (see code). But when Importing it it gives me an error.

Already tried different methods of importing the file. But get the same error. Logging the imported Provider in the component shows that it exists.

**Code**

The exported file

```
function PositionContextProvider({ children }) {
  return <EditModeContext.Provder value={false}>{children}</EditModeContext.Provder>;
}

export { PositionContextProvider };
```

The import

```
import { PositionContextProvider } from './PositionContext';

[...]

function Application() {
  return (
   <ContextQuery query={getPositions}>
    {({ data, loading, fetchMore, isFetchingMore }) => {
      return (
        <PositionContextProvider>
          ...
        </PositionContextProvider /> 
      )
    })}
   </ContextQuery />
  )
}
```

Expected to be able to use the context in any of the components within the Provider but get the error message in the console.

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: You're not returning anything from function inside `ContextQuery` and also there no return in `Application`

Comment: Edited the code example. It was actually returned. Copy & pasted it wrong, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

assign your function to variable then export it:

```
const PositionContextProvider = function({ children }) {
  return <EditModeContext.Provder value={false}>{children}</EditModeContext.Provder>;
}

export { PositionContextProvider };
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo: missing 'i' in Provider..